# How to unit test angular js controller correctly

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Currently i got stuck in writing a unit test for my angular controller. I have a `$scope` Function which makes an ajax request and after resolving all promises it assigns the fetched data to `$scope.products`. But it does not work for me and i don't know what i'm doing wrong here!

#### controller

```
$scope.products = [];

// $q.all is used because i've some other data sources too
$scope.query = function (term) {
    $q.all([
        DataService.autocomplete.products(term)

    ]).then(function (results) {
        $scope.products = results[0].data.content;
    });
};
```

#### Dataservice

```
// dataservice return value
return {
    autocomplete: {
        products: function (term) {
            // _makeRequest is a wrapper for a $http call
            return _makeRequest('autocomplete/products', term);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Unit-Test

```
describe('[Autocomplete] AutocompleteCtrl', function () {
    var $scope, DataService;

    beforeEach(module('Autocompleter'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$q_, _DataService_) {

        var deferred = _$q_.defer();
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        DataService = _DataService_;

        $controller('AutocompleteCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
        deferred.resolve(['resolveData']);
        spyOn(DataService.autocomplete, 'products').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
    }));


    describe('Query', function () {

        it('should resolve promise', function () {
            $scope.query('term');
            $scope.$apply();
            expect($scope.products).toBe(['resolveData']);
        });

    });
});
```

#### Test-Result

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'results[0].data.content')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller expects the DataService.autocomplete.products() function to return a promise, and expects this promise to be resolved with an object which has a `data` attribute, since you're doing:

```
results[0].data.content
```

In your test, you resolve the fake promise with the following value:

```
['resolveData']
```

So, instead of getting an object looking like

```
{
    data: 
    {
        content: 'someValue'
    }
}
```

the controller receives `['resolveData']`.

Obviously, accessing the data attribute of `['resolveData']` will lead to an undefined value.

Comment: OP already state that he use `$q.all()` because there're some other data sources too.

Comment: Fair enough. I missed it. I'll remove this part from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting `.data.content` from the result of `DataService.autocomplete.products()`.

Therefore, you should change your mock data from:

```
deferred.resolve(['resolveData']);
```

to this instead:

```
deferred.resolve({ data: { content: ['resolveData'] } });
```

Hope this helps.